# PHP: CURL - Trying to hit website with &not in the URL

Tags: php, url, curl, special-characters, ampersand

I have a website I'm trying to hit, and it takes GET parameters in the URL.  For example:

```
http://example.com?val=123&notice=abc
```

The issue is the `&not` that starts the `notice` key is being read as html to give me this character: ¬

I've tried escaping the `&` character before `notice` and tried replacing it with `&amp;` but neither works.

Anyone have any clue what to do?

**EDIT**

Here is the relevant code:

```
$url = "https://example.com/extern?type=2&notification-mode=1";
curl_get_contents($url, true, false);
```

And here is the CURL function it calls:

```
function curl_get_contents($url, $body = true, $header = false) {
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, !$body);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Let's see the code you've tried, because this should not be an issue. Maybe you need a trailing slash, like `http://example.com/?val=...`

Comment: Share the code atleast.

Comment: What are you doing get and display the `¬` character?

Comment: Did you copy paste the url ? try typing the url..

Comment: I just tested your script and it works fine for me. `$_REQUEST` contains: `Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [notification-mode] => 1
)`

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you put the URL in quotes.

Comment: The URL is in quotes.  No luck.  I added the code so you can see.

Answer (score 0):

The `¬` character outputs html symbol because you are trying to debug `$url` in html document which causing it to convert the entity to symbol.

By wrapping your url within [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) it will encode the html symbol from `¬` to `&not;`.